# SKStoreProductViewController initialization on non main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, storekit

I am seeing an occasional crash as I initialize SKStoreProductViewController on non main thread. I don't see any docs about initializing it on main thread. 
Do we have to initialize SKStoreProductViewController on main thread?

Comment: Why wouldn't you initialize a view controller on the main queue? Most things in UIKit (and `SKStoreProductViewController` extends `UIViewController`) need to be done on the main queue.

Comment: Because I want to prefetch the app store content before presenting it. So init and call loadProduct method on background thread. When need to present, just use the same instance which has loaded the app store details. It works but seeing the crash on few occasions which I can repro it, error details don't make any sense.

Comment: You don't need to call `init` or `loadProduct` on a background thread. `loadProduct` is already async and will eventually call its completion handler on the main thread where you then present the view controller. It all works just fine on the main queue without locking up the UI.

Answer (score 1):

I just made this as an answer so that it can highlight the point made by rmaddy in the comment.

> Important
>
> Use UIKit classes only from your app’s main thread or main dispatch
>   queue, unless otherwise indicated. This restriction particularly
>   applies to classes derived from UIResponder or that involve
>   manipulating your app’s user interface in any way.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit

And as rmaddy pointed out, the class definition:

```
open class SKStoreProductViewController : UIViewController
```

So yes, you need to use the main thread.